# Remote Desktop Viewer Set-up for 12.10

Tags: 12.10, remote-desktop

How do you set up the Remote Desktop in 12.10?  I've scanned the available answers here and didn't find anything that answers the question considering the 12.10 interface.  Specifically, advice says to check the "Allow Others to Control Your Desktop" and an IP will pop up (10.04 I believe).  But when checking this in Quezal no IP shows.  So how would I connect to my desktop from somewhere other than the local network, like say a coffee house?

I also see this Remmina client program but have no idea if I need to use that as well.

Can someone give me a step-by-step or point me to one that I haven't found yet?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First, signup for a remote log in by clicking remote login onthe login screen and then the question mark, then click setup and then go ahead with your details. You are now ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

Run `vino-preferences`, enable `Allow other users to view your desktop` and any other settings you want, then reboot.

Comment: I've done that, but I'm not sure how to view that computer remotely from that point on.  If I open Remote Login from a laptop after doing this, I'm not sure how to get to MY computer from there.  I know this sounds stupid, but I'm missing something.  Of course that something might just be Team Viewer... :)